# How to mock member functions that modify private variables in a C++ class, using gmock?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googlemock

I am grappling with a problem on mocking using gmock. The simplified example below depicts it. I have public member functions in a class, that neither return any values nor take anything as inputs. They only change some private variables in the class. There is a third method that uses the effects of those 2 methods in order to calculate something (say, p) before spitting out the result to the outside world. I need to know how to mock `update_a()` and `update_b()` properly. To some extent I can mock them. But I just do not know how to associate some "actions" with their mock versions so that by invoking them I can generate some effects on the private variables. Here is what I have so far:

```
class MyClass {

  private:
  int a,
  int b,
  int p;

  public:

  MyClass() : a{}, b{}, p{} {}

  void update_a() {
     a += 2;
  }

  void update_b() {
     b += 5;
  }

  int calculate_p() {
       update_a();
       update_b();
       p = a * 100 + b * 50; // Just some random math making use of a and b.
       return p;
  }
```

}

```
class MockMyClass :public MyClass {

public:
  MOCK_METHOD(void, update_a, (), (override));
  MOCK_METHOD(void, update_b, (), (override));
  int deletegate_to_real() {
    return MyClass::calculate_p();
  }
}

TEST(CalculatingP_Test, otherMemberFunctionsInvoked) {

    MockMyClass mockob;
    EXPECT_CALL(mockOb, update_a()).Times(1);
    EXPECT_CALL(mockOb, update_b()).Times(1);

    mockOb.delegate_to_real();
}
```

The test passes because the test only checks whether the mock versions of `update_a()` and `update_b()` are invoked. But, I am unable to get the mocked versions of `update_a()` and `update_b()` to do something that could directly modify `a` and `b`. Changing the `private` specifier to `protected` is one way I could think of. But wouldn't that compromise the design?

Comment: `friend` testing/mock classes is alternative too.

Comment: Why do you need that? Your Unit Under Test called the methods, yay! That was the point of the tests for tested class. Tests for `MyClass` and whether `update_a()` and `update_b()` do the expected thing will be written separately (without `MockMyClass`)

Comment: @ Yksisarvinen: Yes, you've got a point there. There should be separate tests for update_a() and update_b() without using MockMyClass. But, I have a test case for calculate_p() that needs to assume that a = 20000 and b = 20000. I am not allowed to introduce any new methods, like set_a, set_b, to the current class. I do not want to run loops either, in order to just raise the values of a and b to that high. So, I need some mocking.

Comment: I will try to use protected instead of private, to see if that serves my intention.

Answer (score 0):

You can go further with your DIP:

```
struct IVarAB
{
    virtual ~IVarAB() = default;
    virtual void update_a() = 0;
    virtual void update_b() = 0;
    virtual int get_a() = 0;
    virtual int get_b() = 0;
};


class VarAB : public IVarAB
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
public:
    void update_a() override { a += 2; }
    void update_b() override { b += 5; }
    int get_a() override { return a; }
    int get_b() override { return b; }
};

class MyClass {
private:
  std::unique_ptr<IVarAB> varAB;
  int p = 0;

public:
  MyClass() : MyClass(std::make_unique<VarAB>()){}

  explicit MyClass(std::unique_ptr<IVarAB> varAB) : varAB{std::move(varAB)} {}

  void update_a() { varAB->update_a(); }
  void update_b() { varAB->update_b(); }

  int calculate_p() {
       update_a();
       update_b();
       p = varAB->get_a() * 100
         + varAB->get_b() * 50; // Just some random math making use of a and b.
       return p;
  }
};
```

Then your mock can define return value for both `a` and `b`.

Comment: I understand the design you've put here but it would require me to significantly change the current design, which I am not allowed to do.

Answer (score 0):

It was decided that I could proceed with replacing "private" with "protected". That solves all my problems.

```
class MockMyClass :public MyClass {

public:
  MOCK_METHOD(void, update_a, (), (override));
  MOCK_METHOD(void, update_b, (), (override));
  void set_dummy_a(int arg_a) {a = arg_a;}
  void set_dummy_b(int arg_b) {b = arg_b;}
  int deletegate_to_real() {
    return MyClass::calculate_p();
  }
}

TEST(CalculatingP_Test, otherMemberFunctionsInvoked) {

    MockMyClass mockob;
    EXPECT_CALL(mockOb, update_a()).Times(1);
    EXPECT_CALL(mockOb, update_b()).Times(1);

    mockOb.delegate_to_real();
}

TEST(CalculatingP_Test, shouldCalculateP_basedon_a_and_b) {

    MockMyClass mockob;
    EXPECT_CALL(mockob, update_a()).WillRepeatedly([&mockob]() 
    {mockob.set_dummy_a(20000);});
    EXPECT_CALL(mockob, update_b()).WillRepeatedly([&mockob]() 
    {mockob.set_dummy_b(20000);});
    int expected {3000000};
    EXPECT_EQ(expected, mockob.delegate_to_real());
}
```